# Output of GNU size is misaligned when the binary is larger than 10M

Tags: linux, gnu

The output of GNU [size](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-size-command/) is misaligned when the binary is larger than 10 M, e.g., `size /usr/bin/docker`.

Don't see a way to print eg. 10000K instead of 10000000.

Do I just live with it?